# Are all one-dimensional force fields conservative?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, conservative-field

Just checking a rather small thing: given any open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and any force field $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is conservative since it is the gradient of any of its antideratives.

**Right?**

---

To be clearer, what I mean by a *force field* (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a function $U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ from an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ such that a particle at $x\in U$ experiences force $f(x)$.

Friction does not seem to fall under such definition.

Comment: The answer is yes: on the real line you have path-independence of work and, for a given $f(x)$ you can always calculate the potential $c_0-\int_0^x f(y)dy$. Yes, there may be pathological cases but this is the idea (you can extend the idea of derivative of a discontinue potential by using the Dirac delta distribution).